# Ogre3d 1.9 + xcode 6.1 for iOS 7 give error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?

Tags: c++, xcode6.1, ogre3d

i try to compile Ogre3d 1.9 stable for iOS SDK as is from the site 
but it give me error's i did point in xcode to use libc++ and c++11
as it pointed here : http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Building+From+Source+-+iPhone
now im getting those error's that is ( i guess boost related )

```
In file included from /Users/foo/Documents/3d/Ogre3d/OgreSDK/Samples/Browser/src/SampleBrowser.cpp:42:
In file included from /Users/foo/Documents/3d/Ogre3d/OgreSDK/Samples/Browser/include/SampleBrowser_iOS.h:40:
In file included from /Users/foo/Documents/3d/Ogre3d/OgreSDK/Samples/Browser/include/SampleBrowser.h:31:
In file included from include/OGRE/SampleContext.h:32:
In file included from include/OGRE/OgreLogManager.h:32:
In file included from include/OGRE/OgrePrerequisites.h:32:
In file included from include/boost/tr1/tr1/string:16:
In file included from include/boost/tr1/detail/config_all.hpp:151:
In file included from include/boost/tr1/tr1/utility:21:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:157:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple:16:
In file included from include/boost/tr1/tr1/type_traits:22:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:297:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
template <>          struct __is_nullptr_t_impl<nullptr_t> : public true_type {};
                                                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:297:49: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
template <>          struct __is_nullptr_t_impl<nullptr_t> : public true_type {};
                                                ^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:296:17: note: template parameter is declared here
template <class _Tp> struct __is_nullptr_t_impl       : public false_type {};
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:507:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
template <> struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY is_scalar<nullptr_t> : public true_type {};
                                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:507:52: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
template <> struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY is_scalar<nullptr_t> : public true_type {};
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:500:17: note: template parameter is declared here
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY is_scalar
```

what is wrong here ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: no and no and its really shame , as engine as ogre doesn't evolve proper to mobile , there is so much room to replace unity3d ...

Comment: actually, I did find a solution. my problem was that I was recursively including /usr/local/include. Once I sent it to non-recursive, I had some other issues, but it addressed this one. I'm not sure why it is a problem, but it worked for me.

Comment: can you share more or publish step by step how did you compile Ogre3d
you know just open free blog page or something ... 
for iOS , im sure many will be glad to read it 
Thanks !

Comment: I was just compiling boost, but let me take a look at Ogre3d later

Comment: great massage here when you have working tutorial , this will be great!